# Stripe create customer with coupon at subscription level

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe's [php library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php) to create a customer with a subscription that contains a coupon. I don't want to add the coupon at the customer level, I want to add it at the subscription level. The below code is what I'm currently using and according to their support, this should work, but it doesn't. I was hoping someone will be able to help.

```
$params = array(
    'card'=>'SOME_TOKEN_FROM_JS_LIBRARY',
    'plan'=>'valid_plan_id',
    'coupon'=>'valid_coupon_id'
);

$c = Stripe_Customer::create($params);

if(!empty($params['coupon'])){
    $c->updateSubscription(array(
        'plan'=>$params['plan'],
        'coupon'=>$params['coupon']
    ));
}
```

This successfully creates the customer and charges the card with the coupon applied.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up going with the code below, it does what I want it to do. Also, the goal with the code below is to delete the customer if the charge fails for whatever reason, so I'm not left with customers that don't belong anywhere.

```
$_c = Stripe_Customer::create($params);

try{

    $_c->subscriptions->create(array('plan'=>$plan, 'coupon'=>$coupon));

}catch(Exception $e){

    $_c->delete();
    throw new Exception($e->getMessage());  
}

$c = Stripe_Customer::retrieve($_c->id); //to get the customer object with the latest data
```